# Left Shift Operator, Java : How does 0 / 2 doesn't throws error

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I was looking into this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QYoWR8hDCyQ&ab_channel=Pepcoding), for a really famous question for bit manipulation

He wrote this statement

```
count -= (1 << ((length - 1) / 2));
```

I am not able to understand.
Consider if I pass length as 1, why does this statement doesn't throws `ArithmeticException`
for 0 / 2.

I am missing out the core fundamental over here.
Please help me out here.

Here is the full code for reference:

```
public int solve(int A) {
        if(A == 0)
            return 0;
        
        int result = 1;    
        int length = 1;
        int count = 1;
        
        while(count < A) {
            length++;
            count += (1 << ((length - 1) / 2));
            
        }
        
        count -= (1 << ((length - 1) / 2));
        
        int offset = A - count - 1;
        
        result |= (1 << (length - 1));
        result |= offset << (length / 2);
        
        int halfShiftedNumber = (result >> (length / 2));
        int reversedNumber = getReversedNumber(halfShiftedNumber);
        
        result |= reversedNumber;
        
        return result;
    }
    
    int getReversedNumber(int A) {
        int result = 0;
        
        while(A > 0) {
            int lsb = (A & 1);
            
            result |= lsb;
            
            result = result << 1;
            A = A >> 1;
        }
        result = result >> 1;
        return result;
    }
```

What if I pass 1 as an input to the function.. it should throw ArithmeticException.
But its not..

Can anyone help me, explaining this basic stuff.

Thanks!

Comment: 0 divided by 2 is 0. You can't divide *by* 0, but you can divide 0 by any non-0 number.

Comment: Why so you believe that `0 / 2` should throw `ArithmeticException`?

Comment: My apologies.. I considered it other way...sleepless night does affect your brain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0 / NaturalNumber` is a valid mathematical operation that will result a `0`. So programming languages support the operation. (this applies to negative and floating point numbers too)

In the related context, `0` as denominator is undefined.

So, for `AnyNumber / 0` operation, programming languages can throw exception.

### Issues to consider

Please be aware that when length is zero or negative (so that `length-1` is negative), then it will result in unexpected result.

1. In the context of integer, `somenumber << -value` is similar to `somenumber << ((32 - value) % 32)`
2. In the context of long, `somenumber << -value` is similar to `somenumber << ((64 - value) % 64)`